# Artifactory maven login failed Failed to transfer file Return code is 401, ReasonPhrase Unauthorized

Tags: java, maven, encryption, pom.xml, artifactory

I've recently set up an artifactory instance on my computer to manage all my libraries but I can't get it to work.
I've described all the exact steps I made and the result I found:

1: I've downloaded the lastest artifactory relase from [here](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) (version:4.14.0)(packing:zip)
2: I've unpacked and launched it (clicking at ${ART_HOME}/bin/artifactory.bat).
3: Once it is all started I open my broswer and go in the artifactory's web interface (localhost:8081) and I login as admin.
4: Once logged in I go in the security configuration (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/admin/security/general) and I uncheck "Allow Anonymous Acces", set "Password Encryption Policy" to "REQUIRED" and save.
5: I create another user (from "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/admin/security/users/new") with the following credentials: [ {"User Name", "test"}, {"Email Address", "My personal email"}, {"Password", "pssw"}] and save.
6: I create another Permission (from "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/admin/security/permission/new")  called "Developer" and include any repositories, then I add the user "test", I check any permission and click "Save & Finish".
7: I log out from admin and login as test.
8: I go in the profile (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/profile) and unlock it (inserting the password), then copy the encrypted password to a environment variable called ART_ENC_PSSW (artifactory encrypted password).
9:I go into the artifact page (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/ext-release-local) and, after selecting the first repository ("ext-relase-local"), I click "Set Me Up"  and then "Generate Maven Settings".
10: I read in some forums that if you insert the credentials and downloadi the snippet Artifactory should automatically fill the password and user fields, but after some testing I saw that it's completely useless, anyways I download the snippet and put it in "C:\Users\.m2\settings.xml".
11: I Open the terminal and execute the command "mvn -emp masterpssw" and put the result inside "C:\Users\.m2\settings-security.xml" inserted like this: `<settingsSecurity><master>pssw</master></settingsSecurity>` WITH the brackets (something like {Am93} but longer).
12: Once saved the pervious file I open again the terminal and type in "mvn -ep $ART_ENC_PSSW" (I'm not in linux but you get what I mean) and replace `${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"*** Insert encrypted password here ***"}` with the result (with brackets) in the settings.xml file.
13: I replace `${security.getCurrentUsername()}` with `test` and then I save the document
14:I open some of my projects' pom and I write this after the build tag:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>project-releases</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>project-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/ext-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

14: I open the terminal in the project directory and I execute the command: "mvn deploy"

Error: `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project <project>: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact <package>:<project>:jar:1.0 from/to central (http://localhost:8081/art
ifactory/ext-release-local): Access denied to: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local/<package>/1.0/<project>.jar, ReasonPhrase: Forbidden. -> [Help 1]`

In the request.log 2 lines had been appended: `20161101203536|1|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|non_authenticated_user|PUT|/ext-release-local/<package>/1.0/<project>-1.0.jar|HTTP/1.1|403|1742174
20161101203536|1|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|non_authenticated_user|PUT|/ext-release-local/<package>/1.0/<project>-1.0.pom|HTTP/1.1|403|4148`

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?
Thank you for the time spent even reading this long question.

Comment: Can you share your Settings.xml file (remove the passwords from it)

Comment: It's a bit unclear if you have defined the server in your settings.xml. If you haven't, then the plugin won't pick up the user name.

Answer (score -1):

If you do all the steps in one go (without restarting the pc) try to do so, and if it doesn't work check all the steps, If you follow those steps Artifactory should work proerly